# Regex to match all of a particular repeated word

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE ID IN ('<replaced>', '<replaced>', '<replaced>')
```

Where the "`<replaced>`" part is a string and I want to match on everything between `(` and `)` so I can replace it with "`<replacedlist>`".

The resultant string would be

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE ID IN (<replacedList>)
```

I don't want to just do everything inside brackets as this will match other strings, only when the brackets contain "`<replaced>`" and it's repeated any number of times.

If it's relevant, I'll be using C# to parse it, but I'm not tagging it as this should be general regex.

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: Should `(<replaced>, <otherText>, <replaced>)` turn into `(<replacedList>, <otherText>)`? Or are the `<replaced>`s guaranteed to be next to each other?

Comment: the one built into c#? not sure if there is more information required?

Comment: The idea is to concatenate multiple <replaced> into a single... so providing they are next to each other it's fine to replace them

Comment: @Martin: Ok - just asking, because they all differ in tiny bits of their syntax and handling.

Comment: Is `\(.*\)` pattern ok? I.e. just match everything inside `(` and `)` and replace it with `<replacedList>`.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk, no, there could be other `()` combinations that should be not have the contents replaced.

Comment: So what we should return from `SELECT * FROM blah WHERE ID IN (<replaced>, (SELECT * FROM sth), <replaced>)`?

Comment: The question states what the example text should return, I'm not sure what you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this pattern:

```
(?<=\([^)]*)'<replaced>'(, '<replaced>')*(?=[^)]*\))
```

As in

```
var input = "SELECT * FROM blah WHERE ID IN ('<replaced>', '<replaced>', '<replaced>')";
var pattern = @"(?<=\([^)]*)'<replaced>'(, '<replaced>')*(?=[^)]*\))";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "<replacedList>");

Console.WriteLine(output); // SELECT * FROM blah WHERE ID IN (<replacedList>)
```

Or alternatively, you can use this pattern:

```
(\([^)]*?)(<replaced>(?:, <replaced>)*)([^)]*\))
```

As in:

```
var input = "SELECT * FROM blah WHERE ID IN ('<replaced>', '<replaced>', '<replaced>')";
var pattern = @"(\([^)]*?)('<replaced>'(?:, '<replaced>')*)([^)]*\))";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1<replacedList>$3");

Console.WriteLine(output); // SELECT * FROM blah WHERE ID IN (<replacedList>)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working... each <replaced> is being overwritten with <replacedlist>, I want to concatenate them.

Comment: @Martin I tried it out with thay exact code and got the correct result. I assume `<replaced>` is just a placeholder for what you really want to replace, but perhaps it's having a hard time with the real value. What are you actually trying to replace?

Comment: that is the actual value, a desensitizing script replaces IDs with that, and I want to concat them so I can group them.  I'll try it in console to see if that makes a difference

Comment: @Martin can you post some of the code you're using to perform the replace?

Comment: my bad, the text is actually `'<replaced>'`, i.e with single quotes around

Comment: @Martin so should the result be `'<replacedList>'` or `<replacedList>`--i.e. with or without single quotes?